# How can I calculate the mean over a series of specific, varying width column ranges?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I've a pandas 1D DataFrame (columns: float, values: float) like this one:

```
    1.0     1.1     1.2     1.3     1.4     1.5     1.6     1.7     1.8
0   1.0     2.0     5.0     4.0     3.0     NaN     1.0     7.0     NaN
```

I'd like to calculate the mean over specific row ranges. `NaN` shall be considered as `0.0`. Column ranges do not have a constant column count w.r.t. the overall column range (`1.0 - 1.2`, `1.3 - 1.5`, `1.6 - 1.9`) but have varying column counts w.r.t. overall column range e.g. `1.0 - 1.3` (4 cols), `1.4 - 1.7` (4 cols), `1.8` (1 column). I'd like to get the following DataFrame as result:

```
    1.0     1.1     1.2     1.3     1.4     1.5     1.6     1.7     1.8
0   3.00    3.00    3.00    3.00    2.75    2.75    2.75    2.75    0.00
```

What's the most performant and memory aware implementation to achieve this?

Comment: What do you exactly mean with `varying row counts`? And as far as I can see, it is every 4 columns as a group, corrrect?

Comment: @Erfan I mean col count instead of row count... question fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Method 1 - floor division `//`:

This method assumes you have equal ranges of columns you want to `groupby`, in this case every 4 columns.

```
df.fillna(0).groupby(np.arange(df.shape[1]) // 4, axis='columns').transform('mean')

   1.0  1.1  1.2  1.3   1.4   1.5   1.6   1.7  1.8
0  3.0  3.0  3.0  3.0  2.75  2.75  2.75  2.75  0.0
```

---

### Method 2 - `np.digitize`:

Here we can create customs `bins` of columns to `groupby`:

```
bins = np.array([1, 1.4, 1.8])
grps = np.digitize(df.columns, bins)

df.fillna(0).groupby(grps, axis='columns').transform('mean')

   1.0  1.1  1.2  1.3   1.4   1.5   1.6   1.7  1.8
0  3.0  3.0  3.0  3.0  2.75  2.75  2.75  2.75  0.0
```

Comment: Tried it out. Works perfectly well for me. Thx. Do you know how the implementation scales w.r.t. execution time and memory performance?

Comment: How does your actual dataset look like? What are the dimensions, eg how many rows, columns @thinwybk

Comment: I don't know yet. You've probably the [o notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) at hand ;)